# SM2Engine can encrypt,but how to add envelop on it?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, jce, jca

I can get a public key from a certificate file,and use code below to encrypt a message with sm2engine.

```
public static String encrypt(String data, PublicKey publicKey)
    {

        ECPublicKeyParameters localECPublicKeyParameters = null;

        if (publicKey instanceof BCECPublicKey)
        {
            BCECPublicKey localECPublicKey = (BCECPublicKey)publicKey;
            ECParameterSpec localECParameterSpec = localECPublicKey.getParameters();
            ECDomainParameters localECDomainParameters = new ECDomainParameters(
                localECParameterSpec.getCurve(), localECParameterSpec.getG(),
                localECParameterSpec.getN());
            localECPublicKeyParameters = new ECPublicKeyParameters(localECPublicKey.getQ(),
                localECDomainParameters);
        }
        SM2Engine localSM2Engine = new SM2Engine();
        localSM2Engine.init(true, new ParametersWithRandom(localECPublicKeyParameters,
            new SecureRandom()));
        byte[] arrayOfByte2;
        try
        {
            arrayOfByte2 = localSM2Engine.processBlock(data.getBytes(), 0, data.getBytes().length);
            return new String(Base64.encode(arrayOfByte2));
        }
        catch (InvalidCipherTextException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

But it is not enveloped,I do not know how to add an envelop on it,but I know how to add envelop without sm2egine:

```
public static String encryptMessage(String message, X509Certificate cert) throws Exception {

    CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator gen = new CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator();
    gen.addRecipientInfoGenerator(new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(cert));
    
    OutputEncryptor encryptor = new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.AES128_CBC).setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME).build();
    CMSTypedData content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    CMSEnvelopedData data = gen.generate(content, encryptor);
    String encryptedMessage = new String(Base64.encode(data.getEncoded()));

    return encryptedMessage;
}
```

but now I must use the special algorithm called sm4 as the symmetric algorithm to encrypt the content first,not aes.And then use sm2 to encypt the key of sm4,all as it defined in [pkcs7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315).so how to join these two code fragment?
All special algorithms seem can be implemented by BouncyCastle method,but there is no sm4 in CMSAlgorithm class,but I found a GMObjectIndenrifier.sms4_cbc,and pass it as a parameter,but got a exception:

```
no such algorithm.
```

More info:after I parse the certificate from a file, and call certificate.getSigAlgName(),its name is SM3WITHSM2

Comment: The only supported algorithms are listed in [CMSAlgorithm](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSAlgorithm.html). I perused the code and it appears to me that adding your own support for a new algorithm would be non-trivial. I can't say anything beyond that.

Comment: I know how to implment the algorithm in a main method,but how to add it to BC,or how to create a provider by myself?@JamesKPolk